# Building a Deb package from Python 2.6.5 FOr Debian 5, Failure

Tags: python, linux, bash, dpkg

Good afternoon,

I am building a .deb package on a Voyage6.5.0 (Debian 5 based system) for Python2.6.5 (because the latest python available for that system is 2.5.2-3)

The steps to my build are shown below.

```
apt-get build-dep python2.5
cd /root
mkdir -p ~/src/
cd ~/src/
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/Python-2.6.5.tar.bz2 --no-check-certificate
tar xjpvf Python-2.6.5.tar.bz2
mv Python-2.6.5 python-2.6.5    
      #needed because dpkg doesn't accept capital letters
cd python-2.6.5
dh_make -myemail@gmail.com -c gpl -f ../Python-2.6.5.tar.bz2
dpkg-depcheck -d ./configure
      #list under the packages needed heading is empty 
dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

The error I get is

```
Compiling /root/src/python-2.6.5/debian/python/usr/lib/python2.6/zipfile.py ...
make[1]: *** [libinstall] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/python-2.6.5'
make: *** [install] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: failure: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
a-gw:~/src/python-2.6.5#
a-gw:~/src/python-2.6.5# make[1]: *** [libinstall] Error 1
-bash: make[1]:: command not found
a-gw:~/src/python-2.6.5# make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/python-2.6.5'
> make: *** [install] Error 2
> dpkg-buildpackage: failure: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
>
```

Can anybody help explain what causes this error and how I can fix it?

I am completely new to using dpkg, so please be as explanational as possible. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this workaround can help you: http://bugs.python.org/issue1669349#msg31369

In that report the build stopped at `zipfile.py` too.